Shomer Negia in Case of Danger
In a situation where two people are obligated in shomer negia (for example two single unrelated adults), if one of them is in a relatively minor state of danger, would you be allowed to get in physical contact to help them since it’s not derech chiba (affectionate), or would this only be allowed if it’s a “major” state of danger? (We would also need to define what is considered minor vs major danger but for the sake of this question let’s take the example below as minor danger)
Example: you are on a bus with an aggressive driver. A woman is standing not holding on and the bus driver slams the brakes. The woman will fall and probably sustain minor injuries if you don’t catch her. Would you be allowed to physically get in contact in order to help?

There’s a story of a rabbi who was walking with his student and they saw a woman drowning in the lake under a bridge and the rabbi ran in and carried her out to rescue her. The student was shocked and as the two were continuing on their journey across the bridge, the whole time the student was hung up on how his rabbi could’ve touched this woman. Finally after the constant battering of questions, the rabbi told his students “I carried the woman for 10 seconds, whereas you carried her across this entire bridge” [in his mind]

@CuriousYid, there's also the chassid shoteh in the gemara

The story told by @CuriousYid is also famously told about Buddhist monks and, I'm sure, holy people of many other faiths.

@CuriousYid my grandfather, Rav eliezer Ben David, was against rabbanim speaking about women's tzniut for that reason. He would say they're thinking about women all day. He would also get upset about sheitel politics for a similar reason. Why are you looking at her (hair). Once a Rav complained to him about girls in his schools skirt length and he responded "hassid shoteh, al tistakel"

R Moshe Feinstein (Igrot Moshe YD 2:137) writes

Even though they do not act out of sexual affection, for which reason
there is no Torah prohibition, in any case, it sounds as though they
are prohibited on a rabbinic level even without sexual affection,
unless it is recognizable that [the touch] is not for sexual
affection.

This normally happens to discussions whether it is permitted to shake a woman's hand in a business context (which some permit and some forbid, see here). It appears from his words that, in the context of a possible accident, this prohibition would not apply.
There are further analogies with a doctor allowed to touch a patient of the other genre because he is "preoccupied with his work", and therefore there is no issue of personal affection.
Of course, consult your rabbi
before implementing anything you learn here.

More importantly, Rabbi Feinstein allows most people to ride public transportation to work, knowing fully well that they may bump into people of the other gender.

Yep, the sexual affection comes later.


"Do not be overly righteous" (Ecclesiastes 7:16). If there is a woman drowning in a river and you have the means to save her, do not say, "I will let her drown because how can I go and see her nakedness?" Do not ruin yourself, be considered sinful, and be punished for it. Go and learn from Saul, who spared Agag and made a foolish argument a fortiori, and because of this he was condemned. Likewise, "one of the students of the prophets said to his fellow by the word of God, 'Strike me, please,' and the man refused to strike him" (I Kings 20:35). Because of this, he was punished, and a lion struck him and killed him (Sefer Hassidim 126).

Although the first case is "major", the last one is "minor" (although latter 2 are against a prophecy).

Thanks for your answer but can you please elaborate how the minor case is relevant to the question? Are either of the minor cases you mentioned about shomer negia? It sounds like both were involving two men

It's unrelated but you see that in both major cases like death and minor cases like bruising someone the verse of "don't be overly righteous" applies. You can argue that the minor case was a prophecy so it's major too but at least I answered half the question lol
